# Flutter - Denying permission on camera throws exception

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, camera, android-permissions

Here is my **initializeCamera** code :

```
initializeCamera() async {
    try {
      final cameras = await availableCameras();
      final firstCamera = cameras.first;
      ContextManager.camera = firstCamera;
      setState(() {
        cameraAuthorized = true;
        ContextManager.cameraAuthorized = cameraAuthorized;
      });
    } catch(e) {
      ContextManager.camera = null;
      setState(() {
        cameraAuthorized = false;
        ContextManager.cameraAuthorized = cameraAuthorized;
      });
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Here is my initState code where I call the **initializeCamera** function and after that initialize the CameraController :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      initializeCamera().then((value) {
        if (ContextManager.camera != null) {
          setState(() {
            _controller = CameraController(
              ContextManager.camera,
              ResolutionPreset.medium,
            );
            _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
          });
        }
      });
  }
```

When I am running the code with flutter web from my computer browser I get this popup from my **initializeCamera** step :

[image]

When I click "allow" the rest of the code which is called in the then()
and especially **_controller.initialize()**, which initialize my camera on the device, is executed and the camera starts working. When I click "deny" another part of the code that I customed is run to display a message on the screen, in other words everything works fine.

When I'm running on the Android Emulator everything from my **initializeCamera()** function to **_controller.initialize()** is run without interruption until I get this popup :

[image]

Whether I choose "while using the app" or "only this time" the camera starts working and everything is ok. But when I click "deny" the app throws a *CameraException*.

I tried to wrap this line (which is causing the issue) :

```
_initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize()
```

in try/catch, and also specifying the name of the exception, but nothing worked.

What I don't get here, is that **_controller.initialize()** function is called before the popup show in the emulator, so the camera is initialized on the device before we can actually choose to deny/allow it.

While on the computer you actually get to choose whether you deny/allow the camera before the **_controller.initialize()** function is executed, which make perfect sense to me.

The ways it works on the emulator doesn't make any sense for me, if someone more knowledgeable could enlighten me, thanks.

Comment: you add permissions on Android Manifest?

Comment: Yes, this line : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>